# Looking for help understanding what is happening in this SQL Script that shows key info about SQL Server Autogrowth Events

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, functions, auto-growth

Here is the code below:

```
DECLARE @current_tracefilename VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @0_tracefilename VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @indx INT;
SELECT @current_tracefilename = path
FROM sys.traces
WHERE is_default = 1;
SET @current_tracefilename = REVERSE(@current_tracefilename);
SELECT @indx = PATINDEX('%\%', @current_tracefilename);
SET @current_tracefilename = REVERSE(@current_tracefilename);
SET @0_tracefilename = LEFT(@current_tracefilename, LEN(@current_tracefilename) - @indx) + '\log.trc';
SELECT DatabaseName, 
       te.name, 
       Filename, 
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 3), Duration / 1000000e0) AS TimeTakenSeconds, 
       StartTime, 
       EndTime, 
       (IntegerData * 8.0 / 1024) AS 'ChangeInSize MB', 
       ApplicationName, 
       HostName, 
       LoginName
FROM ::fn_trace_gettable(@0_tracefilename, DEFAULT) t
     INNER JOIN sys.trace_events AS te ON t.EventClass = te.trace_event_id
WHERE(trace_event_id >= 92
      AND trace_event_id <= 95)
ORDER BY t.StartTime;
```

I stumbled on this in SQL Shack when my team was experiencing autogrowth events but could not find the cause. This script was exceptionally helpful in tracking down what caused the autogrowths but uses many concepts I have not worked with like the PATH function, ::fn_trace_gettable, and PATINDEX().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the full steps

- Declarations

```
DECLARE @current_tracefilename VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @0_tracefilename VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @indx INT;
```

---

- Get the full path of the default trace

```
SELECT @current_tracefilename = path
FROM sys.traces
WHERE is_default = 1;
```

---

- Find the position of the last `\` in the path and use that to strip off the filename.

```
SET @current_tracefilename = REVERSE(@current_tracefilename);
SELECT @indx = PATINDEX('%\%', @current_tracefilename);
SET @current_tracefilename = REVERSE(@current_tracefilename);
SET @0_tracefilename = LEFT(@current_tracefilename, LEN(@current_tracefilename) - @indx) + '\log.trc';
```

This one is rather strange, as there is no need to to use `SET @current_tracefilename` twice, you could just do this

```
SELECT @indx = PATINDEX('%\%', REVERSE(@current_tracefilename));
```

---

```
SELECT DatabaseName, 
       te.name, 
       Filename, 
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 3), Duration / 1000000e0) AS TimeTakenSeconds, 
       StartTime, 
       EndTime, 
       (IntegerData * 8.0 / 1024) AS 'ChangeInSize MB', 
       ApplicationName, 
       HostName, 
       LoginName
FROM ::fn_trace_gettable(@0_tracefilename, DEFAULT) t
```

- This table-valued function (more correctly `sys.fn_trace_gettable`) [returns the contents of the trace file](https://sequelserver.blogspot.com/2011/01/reading-sql-trace-files-using.html)

---

- Join `trace_events` in order to get the event name.

```
     INNER JOIN sys.trace_events AS te ON t.EventClass = te.trace_event_id
WHERE(trace_event_id >= 92
      AND trace_event_id <= 95)
ORDER BY t.StartTime;
```

---

It would be better to actually select the path of the `log.trc` trace file directly from `sys.traces`, although it will only show up if the trace is currently running.

And `SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath')` might be an easier method to get the default log and trace location.

Comment: thank you for this!